# Regex Replace Nette and Latte in ApiGen

Tags: php, regex, nette, apigen

I'm using the Bootstrap Template for ApiGen and I want to replace the default source code views with Highlight.js.

This requires me to remove the existing `spans` produced by ApiGen using the Nette `replaceRE` filter.

The original code looks like so:

```
<pre id="source">
    <code>{$source|replaceRE:'~<span class="line">(\s*)(\d+):(\s*)</span>([^\\n]*(?:\\n|$))~','<span id="$2" class="l">
        <a href="#$2">$1$2$3</a>$4</span>'|noescape}
    </code>
</pre>
```

The variable `$4` contains the spans that need replacing, looking like so:

```
<span class="xlang">&lt;?php</span>
<span class="php-comment">/**</span>
<span class="php-comment"> * app/Base/Controller.php</span>
<span class="php-comment"> *</span>
<span class="php-comment"> * Local base controller for application.</span>
<span class="php-comment"> */</span>
<span class="php-keyword1">use</span> Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
```

and so on.

Obviously the code needs to remain unchanged, but the spans:

```
<span class="whatever">leave code alone</span>
```

need to be removed.

I tried a nested `replaceRE` but got parse errors from ApiGen.

```
<pre id="source">
    <code>{$source|replaceRE:'~<span class="line">(\s*)(\d+):(\s*)</span>([^\\n]*(?:\\n|$))~','<span id="$2" class="l">
        <a href="#$2">$1$2$3</a>{$4|replaceRE:'~<span .*?class="(.*?)">~',''|noescape}</span>'|noescape}
    </code>
</pre>
```

Comment: Looks like a job for [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) and [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)

Comment: That won’t work because `replaceRE` essentially just calls `preg_replace` and the result isn’t parsed (just like the result of `{$source}` isn’t parsed again). You can use two different filters like `replaceRE:'a','b'|replaceRE:'c','d'`. Alternatively you can disable the source code highlighter but AFAIK, there is no config option for that, so you would have to edit the ApiGen itself.

Comment: Yeah I ended up creating my own version of ApiGen.  It doesn't look like it's being maintained anymore anyway so I can just keep it in my pocket and use it for our in house builds. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up that highlight.js was the wrong tool for this since ApiGen requires line numbers for source code and hljs doesn't support line numbers.

Ace editor was the ticket.